# Why the same command prints an emoji in python 2 but fails in python 3?

Tags: utf-8, python-3.5, emoji

In python 2.7:

`print('\xF0\x9F\x98\x9E')`

prints a sad emoticon. The same command fails in python 3.5 (prints some squares). Why and how can I solve it?

Using the emoji package did not work either:

`import emoji`

`print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up_sign:'))`

`print(emoji.emojize('Python is :cookie:'))`

also print squares. I tried to follow the suggestions here [Difference between python 2 and 3 for utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635363/difference-between-python-2-and-3-for-utf-8) (thanks to @lenz) but if I type:

`print(u"\1F61E")`
or
`print(u"\u1F61E")`

I still do not get my emoticon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between python 2 and 3 for utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635363/difference-between-python-2-and-3-for-utf-8)

Comment: I agree it is a possible duplicate, but when I use the unicode corresponding to the emoticon here:
https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode


`print('\1F61E')`

I still do not get an emoticon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is:

`print(u'\U0001f61e')`

apparently the capital U is needed to tell that it is an emoticon that it is going to be printed, which is identified by a 8-character-long string.

Comment: Yep, the notation of numeric escape sequences is `\xNN` for code points < 256, `\uNNNN` for values < 65536, `\U000NNNNN` for larger values, with `N` being a hexadecimal digit. Apparently there is also a `\NNN` notation with 3 octal digits, but it's rarely used (I didn't even know about it until I saw it in the linked post).